# How in Laravel filter by relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models which linked with each other:

```
class Task extends Model{
   public function user(){ 
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
   }
}

class User extends Model{
   public function tasks(){ 
      return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'user_id');
   }
}
```

Now I want to create some search or filter system.

There is a form where the user can choose Task only then the User's parameters (age, sex etc)

How can I do this kind of things? I tried to use newQuery on relation but... 
Any help, thanks

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent on how to reference models and relations.

Comment: 1.Are you able to display all data properly as you said `user can choose Task only then the User's parameters (age, sex etc)` 2. Share your exact condition to filter or search  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope i understood you well.
Use nested `where` and `whereHas` as such

```
$tasks = Task::where('condition', $var)
               ->orWhereHas('user', function($q) use ($var){
                     $q->where('condition', 'LIKE', '%'. $var.'%');
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope it will work for you.

use join to get data from two tables

```
function getBuildings($request) {
        if (isset($request->keyword) && $request->keyword != '') {
            $data = $this->where(function($query) use ($request) {
                $query->orWhere('users.column_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->keyword . '%');
                $query->orWhere('users.column_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->keyword . '%');
            });
        }
        $datacount = $this->count();
        $dataArray = $this->select('users.*,task.whatever data you want to get from task');
        if ($request->length == -1) {
            $dataArray = $dataArray->get();
        } else {
            $dataArray = $dataArray->skip($request->start)->take($request->length)->get();
        }
        return [$datacount, $dataArray];
    }
```